# SSL only works if I add the hostname in my local /etc/hosts

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ssl

For some reason, I am only able to access my site via https if I add the domain and ip in my local /etc/hosts file.

Try it yourself!

If I add:
192.237.249.43  familiarsolutions.com

to my local /etc/hosts file, I can connect to https://familiarsolutions.com/ no problem.

If the /etc/hosts file does not have that line, I cannot connect, and the error says "Webpage not available" <-this is in chrome, and there is nothing in the error logs.

Why is this happening? and How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DNS for familiarsolutions.com is pointing to another IP than you're setting in `/etc/hosts`:

```
% dig +short familiarsolutions.com
192.237.225.48
```

So you need to fix your DNS settings.

Comment: Thanks! that IP is the load balancer. I just need to open up port 443 on the load balancer, and all should work. This was driving me nuts!